# 'gpar' element 'lwd' must not be length 0 error that was not previously there

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using this code [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47602744/draw-boundary-by-zip-code-and-create-a-heat-map) to create heat maps at a state level. My previous version of R and R studio was able to run this code but now this part:

```
ggplot() +
geom_cartogram(data = mymap, aes(x = long, y = lat, map_id = id), map = mymap) +
geom_cartogram(data = mypoly.df, aes(fill = value, map_id = group), map = mymap) +
geom_text_repel(data = centers, aes(label = zip, x = x, y = y), size = 3) +
scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rev(brewer.pal(10, "Spectral"))) +
coord_map() +
theme_map()
```

is giving me an error:

```
Error in `geom_cartogram()`:
! Problem while converting geom to grob.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `check.length()`:
! 'gpar' element 'lwd' must not be length 0
```

My previous version of R stuido was 1.3.1073 and R was 4.0.2
Currently I am using R studio 2023.03.1 Build 446 R version 4.3.0

Thank you!

Comment: I get the same error using the example in the `geom_cartogram` documentation. Looks like a bug - you could file an issue at https://github.com/hrbrmstr/ggalt/blob/master/R/geom_cartogram.r